# drupal-scaffold composer append robots.txt

Tags: 9, composer

We recently upgraded to Drupal 9.3.0 with the composer layout.  Each time we execute `composer update` the contents of robots.txt is overlayed with the file located in `core/assets/scaffold/files/robots.txt`.  We would like to append the default `robots.txt` with project unique data.

I included the following in `composer.json` per the documentation I found:

```
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "web/"
            },
            "file-mapping": {
               "[web-root]/robots.txt": {
               "append": "assets/robots.txt.append"
               }
            }
        },
```

I hesitate to create the file `core/assets/scaffold/files/robots.txt.append` as we have been trained for sometime to not change/add any files in the `core/` directory.  Where should `robots.txt.append` be placed to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path is relative to your project root (where composer.json lives), so in your example create a folder called /assets in the root, i.e. a sibling of /web.

If your question is more whether there's a particular path you *should* place it at, then the answer is: not especially. The file isn't part of the web app itself, so common sense might say don't put it in /web, but really it's up to you.

Just make sure it's placed somewhere that won't be overwritten during composer updates, and that it's included with your git commits (so not sites/default/files etc), and you'll be fine.

Comment: I created the file at ```assets/robots.txt.append``` where ``assets/``` is a sibling with ```web/```.  All is working well!  Thanks

Comment: You can also not scaffold it and add the robots txt module.

Comment: @Kevin Though if you do that, then any core changes to robots.txt wouldn't be included automatically.

Comment: Sure, but I have not found a way to support that or cases like .htaccess.